# Anchor account fetch delay

Tags: anchor

curious about the solana-test-validator for integration tests vs the built in anchor test tooling. I've noticed that when I roll my own integration tests, i need to set about a 15 second delay between the transaction and the .fetch(), yet when i run the tests via anchor, the .fetch() works immediately. What's the discrepancy between the two?
The bizarre thing is, in the validator logs, the transactions work incredibly fast, but .fetch() won't recognize them without a considerable delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commitment issue most likely, are you making sure you are waiting for the same level of commitment when you wait for the transaction to confirm and when you fetch?